# Clearest way to execute a single function 5 times in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have a function that I want to execute five consecutive times in Autohotkey. What's the best way to call the function five times in Autohotkey?

After reading a [post](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=4303) I tried

```
for i in range(0, 5, 1){
    MyFoo()
}
```

but that only throws the error "Call to nonexistent function" (for the for line).

Comment: The post you're referring to presents a custom library function, not native code. In order to use it, you need to add it to your script or [include](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Include.htm) it. You will find the respective function code under **Code:**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be as simple as:

```
Loop 5 {
 MyFoo()
}
```

...unless I am misunderstanding something. If it IS that then I bet you kick yourself ;) haha

Comment: This answer is correct.  However, if your error message about the "call to nonexistent function" references the `MyFoo()` line, you may have a 2nd problem with your code; not defining/implementing `MyFoo` correctly.

Comment: Thanks that's what I need. The solution is easy if you know that the right function is called Loop. I didn't and tried to search for 'for'.

Comment: No problem ,glad it worked for you. In fact I think back in the day I searched "for" as well, For coders it's somewhat more obvious than "loop"!